# PHP session interfering with sub-domain session

Tags: php

I have a few websites on the same server with the following domains with the PHP session domain set to '.example.com' so the cookie is shared between the two websites:

- example.com
- shop.example.com

I also have a separate server with the following domain `admin.example.com` and want it to use its own session/cookie. But when there is a `.example.com` cookie, the `admin.example.com` website tries using that value instead of its `.admin.example.com` cookie value, causing session issues...

If I were to delete the `.example.com` cookie, the website works as intended by using the correct `.admin.earlowen.com` value.

I have set `session.cookie_domain` to `.admin.example.com` to no avail. Am I missing anything? Or is just not possible.

Comment: On `admin.example.com` server inside a web directory create a script with code: `<? phpinfo(); ?>` and run it. What values are displayed for the `session.cookie_domain` option?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase it reads: `.admin.example.com`

Comment: It is displayed as value in fields `Local value` and/or `Master value` in data from `phpinfo()` opposite `session.cookie_domain` directive?

Comment: The master has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they share the same domain, they are the same site and share a session.

You can manually override this by using [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) in your admin section.

Something like this:

```
<?php
//this forces the admin page to recognize a different cookie as it's session id
session_name('PHPADMINSESSID');

//start the session normally
session_start();
```

---

There are a few other tricky ways to do this, but you should generally avoid *tricky*, because you can easily forget what you did and not be able to figure it out later. I will explain some of those also for reference though:

- Dual subdomains alter the expected hostname if they can be used, and will cause two different inherent sessions. For example `subdomain.example.com` and `example.com` will share a session, but `subdomain.username.example.com` and `example.com` will not, and will use separate sessions. You should avoid this, because if you decide to implement some backend logic to manage the session and expect them to be shared, this will become very difficult to work around.
- You can also force different sessions using [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php), but this requires that you manually track the id's and will get quite convoluted, and will also require you to set up some sort of data store to keep track of which sessions go to what, which adds a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Easiest way is to just use different `session_name` values for each session.